# P1070 code error for mitsubishi space star

Tags: obd-ii, mitsubishi

A few days ago - started engine in morning and while in neutral and engine cold it immediately revved to 2000 rpm...  much higher than normal... once engine warmed up it drops....   but now engine warning light on.  So RAC friend of mine tested it and it came up with P1070 fault code .. He checked around the engine but nothing looks amiss...  anyone had a similar problem & solution?

thanks

Comment: Welcome to the site. Can you confirm it's a P1070 and not a P0170?

Comment: I don't know codes, never been dealing with OBD (I will start some day :) ). But otherwise it seems like an air leak. Like a cracked rubber tube between throttle body and inlet manifold.

Comment: I have a comprehensive utiity to search for so-called "P-codes", and P1070 is considered a "manufacturer specific" code as opposed to "generic"... this mean that Mitsubishi defines this code for Mitsubishis, and Volksawagon defines this code perhaps much differently for Volkswagons.  And Volkswagon defines this code as "NOx Sensor Short to Positive".  Which is completely meaningless, because Mitsubishi defines this P1070 code as *nothing*, in other words it does not exist according to my resources.  @Zaid I suspect it was P0170 fuel trim.

Comment: Oooo ....sorry its p0170... !!!